# Floating Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, floating

I am trying to create a custom Keyboard for Android.

I have successfully created one, but I am having problems when I move and relocate it, or make it too tall.

If I move it updating x and y coordinates of the Window LayoutParams, when I go upwards the focused EditText goes upwards too, and I need it to keep its place. The EditText also goes up if I create a Keyboard that does not move, but is very tall.

Is there any way to unlink keyboard and the EditText associated with it?

Relevant code, the `MyInputIMethodService`:

```
import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager

class MyInputIMethodService : InputMethodService() {

    private lateinit var keyboardDragDelegate: KeyboardDragDelegate
    private lateinit var view: MyKeyboardView
    private lateinit var mInputMethodManager: InputMethodManager

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mInputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        keyboardDragDelegate = KeyboardDragDelegate(this, window.window!!)
    }

    override fun isFullscreenMode(): Boolean {
        window?.window?.decorView?.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        return super.isFullscreenMode()
    }

    override fun onEvaluateFullscreenMode(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    private val navBarHeight: Int
        get() {
            val resources = resources
            val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
            return if (resourceId > 0) {
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
            } else 0
        }

    override fun onComputeInsets(outInsets: Insets) {
        outInsets.contentTopInsets = view.height + navBarHeight + (window.window?.attributes?.y ?: 0)
    }

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        view = MyKeyboardView(context = this).apply {
            //button listeners here...
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

I have also tried to make the Keyboard fullscreen with transparency, but then the UI behind it cannot be interacted with.

I know it is possible since at least Siwftkey does it.

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onComputeInsets(Insets outInsets) {
    super.onComputeInsets(outInsets);
    outInsets.visibleTopInsets = -1000;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as answer. Please explain your answer/implementation.